# Bulk upsert with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, upsert

I have a Rails 3 application where I need to ingest an XML file provided by an external system into a Postgres database.  I would like to use something like [ActiveRecord-Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) but this does not appear to handle upsert capabilities for Postgres, and some of the records I will be ingesting will already exist, but will need to be updated.

Most of what I'm reading recommends writing SQL on the fly, but this seems like a problem that may have been solved already.  I just can't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure Rails is the right tool for this. Have you considered doing this outside of Rails using existing XML and PostgreSQL tools?

Comment: Once in the database, the inserted data become models used for other purposes, editable through the web etc. we have validations and associations on the model. I worry that breaking out of rails will cause us to duplicate a lot of work and make maintenance difficult down the road.

Comment: If you want ActiveRecord validations to run you will have to insert one record at a time. If you want bulk update + validations then you will have to setup validations/constraints on the db side. If you want efficiency in this case you may have to compromise on code maintainability

Answer (score 7):

You can do upserting on MySQL and PostgreSQL with [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert).

If you're looking for raw speed, you could use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and upsert.

It might be easier to import the data using [data_miner](https://github.com/seamusabshere/data_miner), which uses nokogiri and upsert internally.

Comment: I wish I saw this answer earlier

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PostgreSQL 9.1 you should use writeable common table expressions.  Something like:

```
WITH updates (id) AS (
     UPDATE mytable SET .....
      WHERE ....
     RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO mytable (....)
SELECT ... 
  FROM mytemptable
 WHERE id NOT IN (select id from updates);
```

In this case you bulk process thins in a temp table first, then it will try to update the records from the temptable according to your logic, and insert the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Its a two step thing. First you need to fetch the XML File. If its provided by a user via a form that luck for you otherwise you need to fetch it using the standard HTTP lib of ruby or otherwise some gem like mechanize (which is actually really great)

The second thing is really easy. You read all the XML into a string and then you can convert it into a hash with this pice of code:

```
Hash.from_xml(xml_string)
```

Then you can parse and work with the data...

Comment: We are using happymapper to parse the XML and that is working great. What's making this difficult is the number of objects we want to ingest makes it very slow if we insert/update each object one-by-one.